# Exploding forecast when increasing sample size in ARIMA in R/Python

Tags: programming, arima

I am fitting ARFIMA - eGARCH to time-series log returns in Python using R Rugarch package. The sample size is 2000, and I am doing 1-step ahead forecast. The following is the output

```
 Conditional Variance Dynamics  
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : eGARCH(2,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(12,0,12)
Distribution    : sstd 

Optimal Parameters
------------------------------------
        Estimate  Std. Error     t value Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.021287    0.003462     6.14839 0.000000
ar1     0.542787    0.000082  6659.75884 0.000000
ar2    -0.392375    0.000064 -6101.43666 0.000000
ar3     0.731225    0.000102  7197.18369 0.000000
ar4    -0.386443    0.000063 -6167.48200 0.000000
ar5     0.150615    0.000037  4116.94426 0.000000
ar6    -0.288939    0.000054 -5348.16765 0.000000
ar7     0.232796    0.000044  5282.09465 0.000000
ar8    -0.809897    0.000113 -7199.04032 0.000000
ar9     0.582303    0.000085  6816.71469 0.000000
ar10   -0.210702    0.000044 -4751.43759 0.000000
ar11    0.795572    0.000111  7190.20153 0.000000
ar12   -0.369857    0.000062 -5948.72174 0.000000
ma1    -0.698025    0.000324 -2154.84576 0.000000
ma2     0.434028    0.000132  3293.28328 0.000000
ma3    -0.792481    0.000242 -3279.96665 0.000000
ma4     0.465008    0.000260  1789.43730 0.000000
ma5    -0.165260    0.000253  -652.30069 0.000000
ma6     0.311199    0.000093  3354.92929 0.000000
ma7    -0.306110    0.000091 -3349.74284 0.000000
ma8     0.844868    0.000145  5830.41599 0.000000
ma9    -0.687115    0.000123 -5607.67847 0.000000
ma10    0.246369    0.000068  3618.79384 0.000000
ma11   -0.797917    0.000128 -6236.95580 0.000000
ma12    0.438962    0.000088  4986.13572 0.000000
omega  -0.009447    0.002659    -3.55262 0.000381
alpha1  0.047739    0.047770     0.99935 0.317627
alpha2 -0.007567    0.047962    -0.15776 0.874643
beta1   0.989998    0.000194  5112.96496 0.000000
gamma1  0.263583    0.064669     4.07591 0.000046
gamma2 -0.160119    0.067340    -2.37776 0.017418
skew    1.035755    0.026110    39.66916 0.000000
shape   3.139950    0.236605    13.27084 0.000000

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Residuals
------------------------------------
                          statistic p-value
Lag[1]                        4.243 0.03941
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][71]     35.810 0.62628
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][119]    56.029 0.75254
d.o.f=24
H0 : No serial correlation

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Squared Residuals
------------------------------------
                         statistic p-value
Lag[1]                     0.03815  0.8451
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][8]    0.16537  0.9999
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][14]   0.42526  1.0000
d.o.f=3

Adjusted Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Test:
------------------------------------
  group statistic p-value(g-1)
1    20     7.405       0.9917
2    30    13.111       0.9950
3    40    19.097       0.9969
4    50    32.981       0.9615

Mean forecast -0.020318754215676776
Var forecast 1.0401001687924032
```

As you can see the model fits the data pretty well and forecast is reasonable. However, if I increase the sample size to 6000 and fit the same model coefficients I get exploding forecasts:

```
Filter Mean forecast -148845285.88045484
Filter Var forecast 30725154.575601663
```

The problem disappears if I reduce the ARMA order (eg ARIMA (3,0,3)), but then my standardized residuals serially correlated according to Ljung-Box test, indicating there is valuable information in residuals. So my question is why does the forecast explode and how to solve it without hurting the residual autocorrelation?

Thanks!

Comment: *my standardized residuals are not normally distributed, indicating there is valuable information in residuals*. No, the shape of the distribution does not tell there is information remaining in the residuals. Autocorrelation or ARCH would, but not the shape of the distribution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Residuals, which of course tests for remaining autocorrelation in residuals. Will correct my post